# Sprites in CSS and positionning borders

Tags: html, css, border

I'm facing a little problem with HTML / CSS right now.

First of all, I want to achieve this :

http://s27.postimg.org/wn17ahx5f/de.png

The 4 images are one sprite, that I already manage to cut and position on the page.
The problem is with the border and the text just at the bottom of them.

How can I do it ?
For the moment I have this :

```
                    <div class="stats-number-block-toto">
                        <ul class="icone-stats">
                            <li class="icone-forums"><div class="text-forums">Test text</div></li>
                            <li class="icone-utilisateurs"></li>
                            <li class="icone-sujets"></li>
                            <li class="icone-messages"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

And the CSS :

```
    .stats-block-toto {
    float: left;
}

.stats-block-toto .titre-bloc-toto {
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c7c6c6;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.stats-number-block-toto {
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
}

.icone-stats li {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("img/forumjv/icones-stats.png") no-repeat;
}

.icone-stats .icone-forums {
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin-right: 100px;
 }

.icone-stats .icone-utilisateurs {
    background-position: 33% 0;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.icone-stats .icone-sujets {
    background-position: 66% top;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.icone-stats .icone-messages {
    background-position: 100% top;
}

.text-forums {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

As I said, my sprites are ok, it's the text and the border that fails.

Here is the jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/gc4HT/

Anyone has a solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: JSfiddle please since we don't have access to your sprite image. Also your CSS looks incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle will work: http://jsfiddle.net/rajmathan/AThr4/

HTML:

```
 <div class="stats-number-block-forumjv">
                    <ul class="icone-stats">
                        <li class="icone-forums"><div class="text-forums">Test text</div></li>
                        <li class="icone-utilisateurs"></li>
                        <li class="icone-sujets"></li>
                        <li class="icone-messages"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
       .stats-block-forumjv {
        float: left;
    }

    .stats-block-forumjv .titre-bloc-forumjv {
        float: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c7c6c6;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .stats-number-block-forumjv {
        float: left;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .icone-stats li {
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 60px;


        display: inline-block;
        background: url("http://s27.postimg.org/wn17ahp5f/design.png") no-repeat;
    }

    .icone-stats .icone-forums {
        background-position: 0 0;
        margin-right: 100px;
     }

    .icone-stats .icone-utilisateurs {
        background-position: 33% 0;
        margin-right: 100px;
    }
    .icone-stats .icone-sujets {
        background-position: 66% top;
        margin-right: 100px;
    }
    .icone-stats .icone-messages {
        background-position: 100% top;
    }

    .text-forums {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        padding-top: 15px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
```

Comment: Last question : Is it possible to expand the length (not the height) of the borders to have them more longer like in the image ?

Comment: Are you telling about the width? Except for `background-image:` we need not to give `height:` to avoid the alignment issues generally.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XbaAE/)

Make the width the same size as your text class (`100px`) or remove the `width` property completely.

In my jsFiddle, I made it same size, added a placeholder image so you can see what it would roughly look like and added `text-align:center`; to your text so that your text was aligned center to your image.

The reason the background image looks 'weird' in each `li` is because the `background-position` is changed on all of them and also that it's just running off 1 background image which is repeating each time. But when you use your own sprite and find the right `background-position`, it should look fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm coming closer to the solution !
But when I try with your code and my image, that's what I get :
http://jsfiddle.net/XbaAE/1/
I think the background-position are ok, because it worked before.